# Vim path configuration in OS X

Tags: macos, environment-variables, osx-mountain-lion, macvim, rbenv

I'm trying to set $PATH variable in MacVim to the same value it has in a Terminal.

From these sources I wrote in `~/.zprofile`

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
eval "$(rbenv init -)" # this makes rbenv work

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
echo $PATH >> ~/path # for debugging purposes
```

And this are my results, in ~/path $PATH is correctly defined:

```
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/pills/.rbenv/shims:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

But when I do `!echo $PATH` in MacVim I get a twisted value:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/pills/.rbenv/shims
```

I saw from https://superuser.com/a/47166/145603 how $PATH is set, but I don't get why I'm having this behaviour. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using zsh, it seems. In recent OS X releases, Apple ships a misconfiguration in the form of `/etc/zshenv`. You should fix that with

```
sudo mv /etc/zshenv /etc/zprofile
```

If you still have issues with misconfigured PATH in Vim, try setting this in `~/.vimrc`:

```
set shell=bash  " avoids munging PATH under zsh
let g:is_bash=1 " default shell syntax
```

If you do this, ensure that your `~/.bashrc` is also configured for rbenv the same way your `~/.zprofile` is.

For more information about which shell initialization files get sourced when, refer to the [Unix shell initialization guide](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Unix-shell-initialization)

Comment: Thanks, `sudo mv /etc/zshenv /etc/zprofile` did all the thing.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about my experience with this same issue in [my blog](http://damselem.ghost.io/mac-os-x-zsh-vim-and-path/). It's pretty detailed and I believe it's worth reading the entire post to better understand the root cause with a [solution](http://damselem.ghost.io/mac-os-x-zsh-vim-and-path/#thesolution) on how to properly fix it at the end.

Hint - The problem has to do with the `path_helper` command that is executed in both `/etc/zshenv` and `/etc/zprofile`.